# HTML as a server-side programming language

Tags: html, programming-languages

I was reading a Wikipedia article when I came accross [this page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Server-side_websites_programming_languages.PNG?uselang=fr).

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of HTML used as a server-side *programming language*?

Comment: HTML isn't even a _programming_ language, nevermind a server-side one.

Comment: Perhaps it's in reference to server-side template systems?  I don't see how we can do much more than just guess here.  Is there a wiki page which *references* this file and perhaps provides context?

Comment: English link: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Server-side_websites_programming_languages.PNG

Comment: I know, that's why I put programming language in italics, to emphasize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the information was incorrectly taken from [This blog post](http://blog.stoneriverelearning.com/top-5-programming-languages-used-in-web-development/) (it's the reference on the wiki page you linked)

The image on the blog that relates to server-side programming languages is this: http://blog.stoneriverelearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/blog3.jpg

Looks like whoever transcribed the information confused "Ruby and others" with "HTML" somehow.

All in all this is a good demonstration of why wikipedia isn't a flawless resource.

Comment: Well done! I thought there was something I missed, but it was a Wikipedia error.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is used for rendering contents of a web page.I am not sure if it can be used as a programming language.It is a markup language as I understand.

Comment: Welcome to the commenters club. This answer would be more suitable as a comment, so I've upvoted in order to grant you that privilege.